# awk BEGIN compare multiple variables in if statement

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to compare some floats/version numbers in bash for which i'm using awk BEGIN with if statement.
I was able to do comparison and get proper output when i'm using 2 variables.
But in case of 3 variables i'm not able to get the output.

**Objective**:

What i want to achieve is if the input is between two values 4.8.0 & 4.10.0, ( i.e., **4.8.0 <= inp < 4.10.0** ) then output 1 else output 0.

**CODE Block**

Below is what i wrote:

```
inp=4.9.4
out=`awk -v n1=$inp -v n2=4.8.0 -v n3=4.10.0 \
  'BEGIN {if (n1<n2) printf (0); else if (n1<n3) printf (1); else printf (0);}'`
```

another way i tried is comparing with multiple conditions

```
inp=4.9.4
out=`awk -v n1=$inp -v n2=4.8.0 -v n3=4.10.0 \
  'BEGIN {if (n1>n2 && n1<n3) printf (1); else printf (0);}'`
```

**Queries**:
Please help on how can i achieve same using awk BEGIN if?
Also if there is any other way by which i can compare float inputs?

Comment: Float inputs? These look more like version numbers

Comment: Really? Are you aware that `4.9.4` is **NOT** a float number? As @Thor said, they actually are version numbers.

Comment: I guess you should split both STRINGs into arrays and compare each component of the arrays.

Comment: actually i'm looking for a generalised solution for float as well as for version numbers. So my inputs can be either float numbers as well as version numbers. With 2 variables am able to get output generated for both float and version numbers so i think it is feasible to get this working with 3 variables as well.

Comment: Hmm, would that generally work? Numeric 4.10 < 4.9 but version 4.10 > 4.9, right?

Comment: That's right, didn't notice but that is why my output is not coming as desired. sort -v helps me with my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your [`sort`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/sort/) supports version sort, you can use this quick mechanism:

```
if [ $(printf "%s\n" 4.8.0 "$inp" 4.10.0 | sort -V | awk NR==2 ) == "$inp" ]; then
    : Do something
fi
```

Comment: This works fine for my need. But i also wanted to understand why the above code with awk BEGIN is not working with 3 variables. Is there something wrong with my code or is that a limitation with awk BEGIN.

Comment: This is not "float number sort". It's version sort. You can handle this same pipeline in `awk`, but you will need to separate the fields as `4`,`8`,`0`. `inp_1`,`inp_2`,`inp_3` etc and compare the individual fields...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not the "<" itself but the string compare element
4.9 is bigger (string point of view) than 4.10. in this case you must compare *4.09* to 4.10
so transform the input to be at the same order of comparaison and this depend on your context of versionning

```
inp=4.9.0
out = $(
 awk -v nt=${inp} -v nl=4.8.0 -v nh=4.10.0 \
  '# use a function to compare dotted value 
    function lt( Arg1, Arg2) {
      # split version into elements
      S = ES1 = split( Arg1, E1, /[.]/)
      ES2 = split( Arg2, E2, /[.]/)
      # take longest serie
      if( ES1 < ES2) S = ES2
      # reinit lower and bigger flag
      l=b=0

      # test if bigger, smaller or equivalent
      for( i=1;i <= S && ! ( l || b ) ; i++) {
         if( E1[i] < E2[i] ) l++
          else if ( E1[i] > E2[i] ) b++
         }
      # return 1 if smaller
      return ( l )
      }

   # is between
   BEGIN { print ( lt(nl, nt) && lt( nt, nh)) }
   '
   )
```

note:

- the function splitting the dotted element, number are compare as number when possible
- longer or shorter version number are also compare (empty equivalement element are consider as 0 )